# close modal on submit

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing a crud operation and I want to **close the modal on submit**. If i use data-dismiss on the submit button it will only close the button button the functionality doesn't take place. I want the functionality to take place also the the modal to be closed.

Here is my code

> **component.html**

```
<!-- The Modal -->

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content"> 

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Create User</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="add(title.value,releaseYear.value))"> -->
            <form  #createForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)=" createUser()" >

          <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="firstname.invalid  && firstname.touched">
            <label for="text">First name</label><br>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.user.first_name" name="firstname" required #firstname="ngModel" >
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="firstname.invalid && firstname.touched">
                *First Name is required
              </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="lastname.invalid  && lastname.touched">
            <label for="text">Last name</label><br>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.user.last_name" name="lastname" required #lastname="ngModel">
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="lastname.invalid && lastname.touched">
                *Last Name is required
              </span>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="email.invalid  && email.touched">
            <label for="text">Email</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" [(ngModel)]="user.user.email" name="email" required #email="ngModel">
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="email.invalid && email.touched">
              *Email is required
            </span> <br>
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="email.errors?.pattern">
              *Invalid pattern
            </span> 
          </div>

              <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="role.touched && role.invalid">
                <label for="role">Role</label>
                <select id="role" name="role"
                       class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="user.role" #role="ngModel" >
                  <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.name" >
                    {{role.name}}
                  </option>
                </select>
                <span class="help-block"
                    *ngIf="role.touched && role.invalid">
                     *Role is required
                </span>
            </div>  

          <button type="submit"  [disabled]="createForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

> **component.ts**

```
//Create User
createUser() {
var data= this.user_data;
 let user:any = {};
   user["username"] = this.user.user.email
   user["first_name"] = this.user.user.first_name
   user["last_name"]= this.user.user.last_name
   user["email"]= this.user.user.email

   this.userData["user"] = user
   this.userData["role"] = this.user.role
   console.log(this.userData, "sending data")
   this.Authentication.create_user(this.userData).subscribe(res=>{
//  data.push(res);
   this.getUsersFromServices();  
//  console.log(this.getUsersFromServices);
   console.log('data received after creating user',res);   
   },
   err =>{
  console.error("Error creating user!"); 
// return Observable.throw(Error);

})

}
```

Comment: On the click of the close button fire an http request to save your data, and wrap it inside a promise, in case of success call the modal dismiss, and incase of failure simply display an error message,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend to use angulars reactive forms, your form will be much easier to refactor and to implement, since almost all logic is just located in the component class, and demonstrate it using a simplified example. At first create your template in the following form, of course you should add your classes since it looks like you're using bootstrap.

```html
<div class="modal" #myModal>
  <form  #createForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)=" createUser()" >
    <div>
      <label for="text">First name</label><br>
      <input type="text" formControlName="name "required>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the component class create the form using

```js
export class FormComponent {
  createForm: FormGroup;
  ViewChild('myModal') modal: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.createForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null),
      email: new FormControl(null)
      // etc
    })
  }

  createUser() {
    const userData = {
      user: this.createForm.value;
      role: // where you get role from
    }
    this.Authentication.create_user(userData).subscribe(res => {
      this.modal.nativeElement.modal('hide');
    });
  }
}
```

with the `ViewChild` you get access to the modal and should be able to call bootstraps `.modal('hide')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define global variable in your ts file which helps you to handle displaying the modal:

```
public isModalOn: boolean = false;
```

Next add it to modal html element as a condition:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" *ngIf="isModalOn">
  ...
</div>
```

Then your modal will appear only when the variable is true. You need to also change the value of variable to `true` on click method which invokes the modal window.

Last step is to bring back the variable value to `false` on the end of method which submits the modal:

```
createUser() {
  ...
  this.isModalOn = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work but the problem is after the modal closes the screen gets greyed out and I'm unable to click on any links

Comment: Are you sure then you put `*ngIf` directive in the right place? It should be on the very top modal element.

Comment: I found out the issue. After submission the modal-backdrop class is getting appended to the modal. I'll have to find a way to remove that. If you know how to do that it would be helpful.

Comment: It means that something might be wrong with the logic. What styles this class contains? It is just workaround but you could try to remove / switch off styles added by `modal-backdrop` class by adding `[ngStyle]="{ 'PROPERTY' : CONDITION ? 'VALUE_if_true' : 'VALUE_if_false'}"` to element on which that class appears. For example `[ngStyle]="{ 'disable' : isModalOn ? '' : 'none'}"`. It might be necessary add also `!important` to those styles, which I don't like but sometimes helps.